# Why is my input not updating? - React

Tags: reactjs

I can't figure out why my `input` is not updating.  Here is my code:

```
state = {
    org: {
        orgName: ''
    }
};

updateInput = field => event => {
    this.setState({
        [field]: event.target.value
    })
}

render() {
    let { org } = this.state
    return (
        <input
            value={org.orgName}
            onChange={this.updateInput('orgName')}
        />
    )
}
```

I type data into the `input`.  It calls `updateInput` and sets the `state`.  When `render` is called, the `org.orgName`is `''` again.  This should be working.

I have even added a log in the `setState` callback:

```
this.setState({
        [field]: event.target.value
}, () => console.log(this.state.org))
```

and it logs out the `org` info that has been entered into the `input`

What am I missing?  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nested object in your state - you are updating `this.state.orgName` instead of `this.state.org.orgName`

```
updateInput = field => event => {
    this.setState({
        [field]: event.target.value
    })
}
```

needs to be

```
updateInput = field => event => {
    this.setState({
        org: {
            ...this.state.org,
            [field]: event.target.value
        }
    })
}
```

Would recommend you avoid nesting objects in state though going forward.  Will prove difficult to optimize later on.